# Move LI up one level in nested UL using JQuery

Tags: jquery, list, nested, append, parent

I would like to be able to "move" a DOM node (an LI) in a contenteditable DIV to the next highest UL using Jquery. So in the following...

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3
<ul>
<li>item A</li>
<li>item B</li>
<li>item C</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to be able to move item B up a level to the UL containing items 1,2, and 3. This is the current code that does not work for whatever reason (its all keyboard shortcut based, depending on where the cursor is at execution, hence the getSelection() strategy):

select the current node...

```
var $current_node = document.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement;
```

"move" the current node to the 2nd parent UL ([0] is the immediate UL we are already within)...

```
$($current_node).parents("ul")[1].append($current_node);
```

Unfortunately, the console reports this error...

*Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parents(...)[1].append is not a function*

What am I missing? I have a feeling I am not understanding the difference between a JQuery Object and a DOM element selected using Javascript.  I had to rack my head to figure out that `$current_node` needed to be wrapped in `$()` to have access to `.parent()` but I think am still off on something pretty basic. Thanks!

Comment: Edit: I Misread the HTML structure, is the `item 3` and `li` containing a `ul` ?

Comment: [#] breaks an element out of the jQuery object that contains it.  append is a jQuery function, which you no longer are operating upon.  use eq(#) instead of [#] in this case to keep it a jQuery object.  This is the reason for your Uncaught TypeError.  It may not be all your issues.

Comment: I know it looks wierd @HenryDev but the structure is accurate for a nested UL list.  Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists2

Comment: @Taplar eq(#) did indeed get rid of the TypeError... but still not working.

Comment: @Hank I have posted my solution that moves "item B" up one level. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var elementToBeMoved = $("ul  > li:eq(4)");
 $("ul").append(elementToBeMoved);
 $("ul  > li:eq(5)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3
    <ul>
    <li>item A</li>
    <li>item B</li>
    <li>item C</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: The idea though is to be at ANY level of the nested UL and be able to "move" the LI up a level, regardless of how deep the tree goes.  This seems to copy the LI to ALL ULs then deletes it from the undesirable locations. Could get unruly for 12 levels with index counts to manage etc. JQuery docs say _You can also select an element on the page and insert it into another... If ...inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)_ which seems more appropriate.  My problem is getting `append()` to work with however I am selecting the parent node.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I am too lowly to vote yet! Same question though... why `append()` won't accept `document.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement`?

Comment: It worked! I guess I don't suck as bad as I thought.

Comment: @Hank a good tip is to always do a lot of reading on your own. That's how most developers learn. The BEST source by far on Javascript is : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer because I think this is the heart of the issue I was having trouble with, which may be slightly different than it was interpreted/answered above.

```
//select the node using a javascript function getSelection()...
var current_node = document.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement; //node of current line's parent`

//test the var
console.log(typeof current_node); // IS javascript object
console.log(current_node instanceof $); //IS NOT a JQuery object

// by wrapping the var in $(), it can be operated on by JQuery functions, effects, etc...
console.log($(current_node) instanceof $); IS a JQuery object
$(current_node).fadeOut("slow");
```

It was the "passing" bewteen Javascript and JQuery I was having trouble understanding.